# My add_action (wp_footer, 'method') is not calling?

Tags: hooks, actions, footer

In my themes functions.php file I have put:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'method');

function method()
{
echo "this is being called";
die();
}
```

My wordpress footer.php file looks like this:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

What could be the reason my add_action hook is not being called?

I can provide additional code or information if needed.

### EDIT:

Instead of `die()` if I echo a script it won't appear in the pages footer

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'method');

function method()
{
echo "<script>...</script>";
}
```

Comment: why are you using `die()`? perhaps that is your problem.

Comment: I want to see if it is being called. If I put echo '<script>..</script>', save it and inspect the page I don't find the script in the footer

Comment: Pretty sure KnightHawk is right.  You are likely killing the application before it generates output.

Comment: I apologize. die() was a bad example

Comment: Are you checking it in Dashboard?? (probably you aren't :) ). If yes, use admin_footer hook for it.

Comment: @WisdmLabs I replaced wp_footer with admin_footer and it worked so you can put that as an answer and I will accept it. Are there any downsides to this?

Also I was checking it in the dashboard to begin with

Comment: @BDillan Happy to help you. There are no downsides to this. Added my answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a WordPress footer hooks are different for back-end(dashboard) and front-end.

In Dashboard use "`admin_footer`" hook.

In Front-end use "`wp_footer`" hook.

Comment: Argh, this seems so easy and still I failed to remember! Thank you. Can't I upvote 3 or 4 times? :D :D

Answer (score 0):

With such a general function name like `method()` a collision could be happening. Try something a little more unique than that. Also, if you have access to the server you could also print it to the error log so you don't have to worry when the page is being rendered.